# IE9 causes all webpage text to render as Italic when font-family:'Goudy OldStyle'

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9

I just downloaded and installed IE9 and used it on our intranet web pages. This problem only occurs when the font-family is set to Goudy Old Style. When I changed the `font-family` to Verdana the page rendered properly( that is according to the stylesheet). The problem does not occur in Firefox.  It didn't help to specify `font-style:normal` in the default `BODY` style.

When I inspect the dom object in the developer mode I can see the style applied to the object and it matches what is in the stylesheet.  I am relying on inheritance in that the default style defined in the body is `font-style: normal`.  Is appears that the font face for Goudy Old Style does not have a normal mode.

The page is generated by a servlet on a WL Server 81.  I'm not sure if this is related but I'll make a change tonight when I have access to server.
Current:

```
sb.append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"");
```

Will change to:

```
sb.append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n");
```

I appreciate any help since the client has made this problem a priority.

**Revised: Adding page source - Here is the source of the page in question. Unfortunately the page is behind a firewall.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>HALL 2011-2012 SEASON</TITLE>
<LINK REL="STYLESHEET" TITLE="style" HREF="stylesheets/default.css" TYPE="text/css">
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
BODY { font-family: "Goudy Old Style", serif; font-size: 11pt; font-style: normal; }
TABLE { page-break-before: auto; page-break-inside: avoid; }
H1 { page-break-before: always; }
H1:first-child { page-break-inside: avoid; }
.Event { page-break-inside: avoid; }
.EventTitle { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.OrdinarySeriesName { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.HighlightedSeriesName { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.Location { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.Licensee { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.CancellationNotice { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.EventTime { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.SpecialTitle { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.Appearance { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.SubTitle { font-style: italic; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.Repertoire { margin-top: 0.75em; margin-bottom: 0; }
.ProducerCredit { margin-top: 0.75em; margin-bottom: 0; }
.GeneralInfo { margin-top: 0.75em; margin-bottom: 0; }
.PreConcertActivities { margin-top: 0.75em; margin-bottom: 0; }
.SponsorCredit { margin-top: 0.75em; margin-bottom: 0; }
.SponsorComment { color: #808080; margin-top: 0.75em; margin-bottom: 0; }
.TicketInfo { margin-top: 0.75em; margin-bottom: 0; }
.Event TD { page-break-before: auto; }
.Series { page-break-before: always; }
.Series:first-child { page-break-before: auto; }
.SeriesEventTime { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 1.5em; }
.SeriesSpecialTitle { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; }
.SeriesTitle { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
.MailProlog { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.Index { font-size: x-small; }
.LicenseeDescription { display: none; }
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY><IMG SRC="/images/logo1.gif" ALT=" HALL" BORDER=0 WIDTH=249 HEIGHT=43><H1 STYLE="page-break-before: auto;"><A NAME="Index">Index</A>
</H1>
<HR><TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER=0>
<TR><TD VALIGN="BASELINE" WIDTH="40%"><H2><A NAME="Oct">October</A>
</H2>
</TD>
<TD VALIGN="BASELINE" WIDTH="60%"><H3>Jump to:&nbsp;Oct&nbsp;</H3>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE CLASS=Index WIDTH="100%" BORDER=0>
<TR><TD VALIGN="TOP" WIDTH="40%"><A HREF="#13028">MARIINSKY ORCHESTRA<BR>OPENING NIGHT GALA</A>
</TD>
```

Comment: Are there browsers that it is NOT italic in ?

Comment: You can also [mimic a previous version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx), although you'd probably be better off fixing it.

Comment: Can you view source and show us a paragraph or two?

Comment: I have tried the different compatibility modes available in the Developer subwindow and the font style is still italics. I will try to use the font-family as a workaround. Is there a quick way to obtain a Goudy Old Style.eot file?  Also, Is it crazy to think that Microsoft failed to deploy IE9 with Goudy Old Style 'normal' font?

Comment: Not crazy at all. I see this too in IE9 on Win7. It's easy to reproduce too. Just use the IE9 dev tools (F12), and change the font family on anything you like to Goudy. My solution: Veranda. Sounds like you don't have such a liberty though. Just when IE sucked less for a second there...

Answer (score 0):

If you use this font stack:

font-family: Garamond, "Big Caslon", "Times New Roman";

the difference between Goudy and Garamond isn't that big (at least the versions on my computer).

The difference between Goudy italic and Garamond is MUCH bigger!

You could go down the font-squirrel route but there's extra page weight if not using pre-installed fonts to consider.