# Why does Goudy Old Style only display in italics in IE9?

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9

This is related to question [7910391](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910391/ie9-causes-all-webpage-text-to-render-as-italic-when-font-familygoudy-oldstyle), but I don't see it as a duplicate, since the other question is about CSS. I want to know why the browser is failing here.

Try this out:

- Open IE9
- Open IE9 dev tools (F12)
- Select a text element
- Change the font-family on it to "Goudy Old Style"

If you're like me, you'll find the text is suddenly in italics. Why?

I'm on Win7...don't know if this is specific to this OS, but I do have normal Goudy font on the system.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that IE is using it's own fonts library separate from that of Windows, and it doesn't contain the non-italicized version of the font.

Comment: A solid theory. I'd love substantiation and understanding for it.

Comment: I am almost positive this is *not* true, as it would make no sense whatsoever. It is more likely a bug in IE9 that is preventing it from recognizing/using the `normal` variant of the font.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to make a font face (they will override system & browser fonts.)

Start here:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com

Comment: For the record, 1) The OP has already said, *twice*, that he's not interested in a CSS solution, he's asking *why* the browser is acting this way, and 2) If you bothered to check it yourself, Font Squirrel doesn't have this font.

Comment: @BoltClock You upload your own font and it generates the files type, the CSS and everything. Just locate the font on your disk

Comment: @user1090389 It's not always easy to do, but please keep in mind that when answering a question Stack Overflow, it's important to answer the question that the person is asking. Sometimes an 'alternate solution' is appropriate as an answer, but in this case your answer does not provide an alternate solution: Font Squirrel does not have the font in question available

Comment: @AndrewBarber Font Squirrel is where you can upload a font from your computer, have it converted into different formats and delivered to you in a kit. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator. All he had to do was upload his font from his computer.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer the "why" but in case you are looking for a solution you could try a similar font. "Garamond, "Big Caslon", "Times New Roman" works well for me and is MUCH less of a difference than the italic!